# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How do I make it send a message every day at a certain time?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make the bot send a message every day at 1pm. Here's my code:

```
@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def called_every_day():
    channel = client.get_channel(800476409587171369)
    print(f"Got channel {channel}")
    await channel.send("Your message")

@called_every_day.before_loop
async def before():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")

called_every_day.start()
```

This works, **if** I start up the bot at 1pm. However, any time I edit the code and restart the bot, it restarts the loop. I want to prevent this from happening, how would I go about doing so? I'm new to programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen the [Schedule API](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/)? Maybe this could help you

Answer (score 3):

You can use `APScheduler` and `Cron` to schedule your commands to be sent at a specific time, like 12:00 PM

Docs: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/cron.html

Here is an example:

```py
# Async scheduler so it does not block other events
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

async def func():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    c = bot.get_channel(800476409587171369)
    await c.send("Your Message")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")
    # Initializing scheduler
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    # Executes your function at 24:00 (Local Time)
    scheduler.add_job(func, CronTrigger(hour="24", minute="0", second="0")) 
    # Starting the scheduler
    scheduler.start()
```